# How to compile a number from multiple cells

Tags: ms-access, barcode

Let's assume I have a table, where I state the characteristics of the products (color, size, functionality, etc).

Example:

```
01 (black), 02 (medium), 04 (cutting)
```

Based on that information I want to construct a product id, which should look like this:

```
010204
```

so basically cutting all the text from the cells and merging numbers together.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Is each data element in its own field? Always 2 character number with 0 prefix? If this is one long string of text, then will require VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each of your properties always start with two digits, you could use the following to assemble the product ID:

```
left([color],2) & left([size],2) & left([functionality],2)
```